# Radon-Nikodym derivative of discrete measure

Tags: proof-verification, lebesgue-measure, weak-derivatives

Suppose we have a discrete measure
$$ \mu = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \delta(x-x_i)$$
where 
\begin{equation}
\delta(x-x_i) =
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } x = x_i \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation} 
Obviously, for any function $f$, we could integrate $f$ w.r.t. $\mu$
$$ \int f d\mu = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i f(x_i). $$

The question is that can we write 
$$ d\mu = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \delta(x-x_i)dx ??? $$
In the first glance, I thought it is true. 
But it seems that the meaning of $\delta$ changes in this case. 
In the weak sense, $\delta$ is defined as 
$$ \delta(x-x_i) = 
\begin{cases}
\infty & \text{if } x = x_i \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
with
$$ \int f(x)\delta(x-x_i)dx = f(x_i). $$
Am I on the right track?

Comment: Well, note that $\mu(\{x_i\}) = a_i >0,$ and $\lambda(\{x_i\}) = 0,$ so $\mu \not \ll \lambda,$ and so you can't invoke the R-N theorem. Similarly note that the (Dirac-)$\delta$ as proposed is impossible (it's supported on a zero set but has non-zero integral). There are standard ways to deal with the same, the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#As_a_distribution) is a decent start.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. You're right. R-N cannot apply. Then how can I interpret the integration with the discrete measure $\mu$. In weak sense, the delta function is $\infty$ at $x=x_i$. But not in the discrete measure.

Comment: Okay, we'll define the measure $\mu$ in the following way - Consider the measurable space $(\mathbb{R}, 2^{\mathbb{R}}),$ and let $\mu(E) := \sum_{i \in [1:n]} a_i \mathbf{1}\{x_i \in E\}.$ Show that $\mu$ is a measure. Now the integration w.r.t $\mu$ follows in the usual way. 
The idea that a function like the Dirac delta can be seen as a density of this measure is a useful, if incorrect one. One can be formally correct by just dealing with the $\mu$ defined above as a measure in itself, or by going to the theory of generalised functions, both of which have their uses.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Thank you for your comments. Very useful and very helpful :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we're talking about mathematical correctness then no, you absolutely cannot write $ d\mu = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \delta(x-x_i)dx$. Because $\delta$ is *not a function*. People do write that, but it's at best hideously sloppy.

Note that btw the definition of $\delta(x-x_i)$ is not what you say it is. If we're doing measure theory then there's no problem with a non-negative function taking the value $\infty$.But if we define a function $\Delta(x-x_i)$ by$$ \delta(x-x_i) = 
\begin{cases}
\infty & \text{if } x = x_i \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

then we have $$\int f(x)\Delta(x-x_i)\,dx=0$$
for every $f$, since $f(x)\Delta(x-x_i)=0$ almost everywhere. That's not the same as $\int f(x)\,d\delta(x-x_i)$, which equals $f(x_i)$.

"In the weak sense" the definition of $\delta(x-x_i)$ is in fact $$\int f(x)\,d\delta(x-x_i)=f(x_i)\quad(f\in C(\Bbb R).$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Then do you mean that the expression of $$ \int f(x)d\mu(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n a_if(x_i) $$ is written in weak sense? But the delta function in the discrete measure $\mu$ is 1 at $x=x_i$, not $\infty$. If it is not written in weak sense, how should I interpret that expression?

Comment: @induction601 I don't know what you mean by "in the weak sense". I also don't know what you mean when you ask how to "interpret" that equation.